# ¿Esto se considera Inyección de Dependencias?

Tags: java, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Quisiera saber si esto se considera como Inyección de Dependencias.

```java
public interface Animal {
    void comer();
}

public class Controlador {
    
    private Animal _animal = new Gato();

    public Controlador() { }
    
    public void comerImpl() {
        _animal.comer();
    }
}


public class Gato implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void comer() {
        System.out.println("Estoy comiendo como un Felino");
    }
}

public class Perro implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void comer() {
        System.out.println("Estoy comiendo como un Canino");
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variable de tipo interfaz, pero referenciando a la clase Perro
        Controlador controlador = new Controlador();
        controlador.comerImpl();
    }
}
```

Como se ve estoy inyectando dentro del Controlador un objeto del tipo de la interfaz, pero haciendo referencia a cualquier implementación que quiera, en este caso la implementación de `Perro`, pero si quisiera podría cambiar la implementación a `Gato` simplemente cambiando la referencia con `new Gato()`. Mi pregunta: ¿Es esto inyección de dependencia?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analicemos esta clase:

```java
public class Controlador 
{
    private Animal _animal = new Gato();

    public Controlador() { }
    
    public void comerImpl() {
        _animal.comer();
    }
}
```

Aquí lo que estás haciendo es definiendo una dependencia (que en realidad es el objeto de tipo `Gato`, ya que la clase `Controlador` **depende** de la clase `Gato`) adentro de la clase `Controlador`, pero eso no es inyección de dependencias.

Cuando hablamos de inyección de dependencias es cuando le **pasas (inyectas)** una dependencia a la clase `Controlador` (en este caso, claro) por medio del constructor o ya sea definiendo un *setter*.

**Ejemplo**:

```java
public class Controlador 
{
    private Animal _animal;

    public Controlador(Animal _animal)
    { 
         this._animal = _animal;
    }

    public void comerImpl() 
    {
        _animal.comer();
    }
}
```

Luego su modo de uso sería:

```java
public class Principal
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Controlador cont1 = new Controlador(new Perro());
        cont1.comerImpl();
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo de uso notamos que le pasamos (inyectamos) la dependencia al objeto que haga referencia `cont1`, ya que este objeto dependerá del objeto `Perro`.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> > ¿Esto se considera Inyección de Dependencias?

Respuesta: **No**, porque la clase `Controlador` en ningún momento recibe dependencias.

> > Como se ve estoy inyectando dentro del Controlador un objeto del tipo de la interfaz, ...

No estás inyectando nada, porque estás creando el objeto en la misma clase. Si estuviéramos pasando el objeto al constructor de la clase `Controlador`, ahí sí estamos *inyectando* una dependencia a la clase.

**Observación:**

[Las variables en Java no deben empezar con guion bajo..](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#:%7E:text=Variable%20names%20should%20not%20start,the%20intent%20of%20its%20use.)

**Fuente:**

- [Inyección de Dependencias en Java](https://dev.to/cchacin/inyeccion-de-dependencias-en-java-44cg)

**Edición 1:**

> > Cuando dentro del parámetro envió un `new Perro`, que estoy enviando? se supone que se esta esperando una variable de tipo de la interfaz, pero le estoy pasando un `new Perro`

Lo que estás enviando al parámetro `_animal` es una [referencia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), devuelta por `new Perro()` y esto nos servirá para identificar o referirnos al objeto.

Ahora, si quieres saber *literalmente* lo que guarda el parámetro, será difícil, porque eso es un **detalle de implementación** que es transparente por el programador. Lo único que debes saber es que la variable guarda un identificador y con eso nos podemos referir al objeto.

Comment: Gracias por la Respuesta... tengo otra pregunta pequeña. Cuando dentro del parametro envio un new Perro, que estoy enviando? se supone que se esta esperando una variable de tipo de la interfaz, pero le estoy pasando un new Perro.

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses He editado la respuesta para aclarar dudas. No olvides de [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) que resolvió tu problema :)

Comment: Entonces dentro del metodo Constructor se podría decir que internamente cuando recibe el parametro podria verse así , dentro del constructor... :                this._animal = new Perro();   Muchas gracias, me quedo todo muy Claro  :)

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses Así no se vería como tal, porque estarías creando un objeto nuevo. Lo que se le asigna a `this._animal` es la dirección de memoria que tiene guardado el parámetro `_animal`, que en nuestro ejemplo sería la dirección `0x20`. En pocas palabras, lo que tiene guardado el parámetro `_animal` lo almacenas en `this._animal`.

Comment: El parámetro no recibe la dirección de memoria del argumento. Indirectamente sí, pero directamente no. En realidad lo que recibe es el identificador único de objeto del objeto creado con `new`. Dicho identificador lo asigna la JVM, y las variables que "contienen" objetos, en realidad lo que contienen es el identificador de objeto del objeto al que hacen referencia. Obviamente ocuparán una dirección de memoria, pero en general no va a coincidir con el OID. Así que es parecido a un puntero, pero con OIDs en vez de direcciones de memoria.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez Entonces, lo que recibe la referencia `_animal` es un OID? Se supone que las [referencias de Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) se implementan como punteros y si es así, internamente (transparente para el programador) se guarda una dirección de memoria.

Comment: Sí, lo que recibe una variable a la que se le asigna un objeto es el `OID` del objeto creado. En `Animal a = new Gato();` al ejecutar el `new` se reserva espacio para el objeto y se le asigna un identificador de objeto, que es lo que recibe y almacena la variable `a`, para más tarde llamar al constructor de `Gato`. El cómo se implementan esos `OID` es responsabilidad de la `JVM`. Pueden estar implementados como direcciones de memoria, pero puede que sean diferentes, y añadan un nivel de indirección. Así que mejor no confiar en una sola implementación cuando el estándar no la impone.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez Sí, tienes toda la razón. He editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

No, porque el new esta "hardcodeado" dentro del controlador por lo que veo, por lo cual no hay un punto de inyección. Siempre tienes el mismo animal (gato en este caso). Ahora, si tu controlador tuviera un constructor que recibiera un Animal como parámetro o si tuvieras un método tipo setAnimal podríamos empezar a hablar de inyección de dependencias. Luego hay varios frameworks que te ayudan con esto